# Update label C#

Tags: c#, asp.net

When the page first load i have a label who has 0 or 1. Look at the code and you will se what i trying to do. But it don't work because the page allready loaded.

```
protected void rptBugStatus_ItemDataBound(object sender, RepeaterItemEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.Item || e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.AlternatingItem)
        {
            Label lblName = e.Item.FindControl("lblBugStatus") as Label;
            if (lblName.Text == "1")
            {
                lblName.Text = lblName.Text + "Under arbete";
            }
            else if (lblName.Text == "0")
            {
                lblName.Text = "Fixad";
            }
            else { }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Where during the page lifecycle, are you calling this code?

( Page_Load, Page_Init, etc... )

Comment: step through your program and check to see if lblName is returned with an actual object after Findcontrol

Comment: The code is calld when the page is load, beacause the repeater call that funtion when its load

Comment: Set a breakpoint on the line [Label lblName = e.Item.FindControl("lblBugStatus") as Label;].  If the breakpoint isn't being hit, you either have a markup problem on your repeater control, or you don't actually have any data bound.

Comment: if it doesn't return null, then what does lablName.Text read  when you compare it to 1?

Comment: What is it doing that's incorrect?  How is the observed behavior different from what you expect?

Answer (score 1):

You really want to avoid this type of coding if at all possible.  This will quickly grow into an unmaintainable web site.

Query the underlying data instead of GUI elements.

Answer (score 0):

where you put your code? and be cautious `e.Item.FindControl("lblBugStatus") as Label;` may return null

Comment: it's don't return null, i have check that.

Answer (score 0):

it's just work fine to fine the control. But i figure out another way to get out the data i want. That i'am going to is fix the xml structur better.

Comment: what way was that..i'm curious

Answer (score 0):

You may have resolved this by now, but I think the problem with the code as you posted it is this:

```
Label lblName = e.Item.FindControl("lblBugStatus") as Label;
```

Because you are referencing a control in a repeater, the controls inside each repeater item are named dynamically based on their context. Most likely the name of the control is something like:

"rptBugStatus$repeaterItem0$lblBugStatus"

To find out the exact name, hard code a value, run the page in a browser, and look at the HTML output (via "View Source" in the browser menu). You should be able to scroll down and see your repeater (it will be rendered as a `<table>` tag), its items, and the controls living inside each item. The IDs/Names will be set and you can copy/paste them into your FindControl method.

Hope this helps,

Nate

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I am taking the assumption you have set this label (assuming to be in the repeater, from your code) to have a value - I have tried databinding to something exactly the same, using the below code.

```
protected override void OnPreRender(EventArgs e)
{
    base.OnLoad(e);
    List<string> strList = new List<string>();
    strList.Add("1");
    rptBugStatus.DataSource = strList;
    rptBugStatus.DataBind();
}

protected void rptBugStatus_ItemDataBound(object sender, RepeaterItemEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.Item || e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.AlternatingItem)
    {
        Label lblBugStatus = e.Item.FindControl("lblBugStatus") as Label;
        // have added this just so we are actually setting the text property on the bug status
        // - i have assumed you do this.
        lblBugStatus.Text = e.Item.DataItem.ToString();

        if (lblBugStatus.Text.Equals("1"))
        {
            lblBugStatus.Text = lblBugStatus.Text + "Under arbete";
        }
        else if (lblBugStatus.Text.Equals("0"))
        {
            lblBugStatus.Text = "Fixad";
        }
    }
}
```

With the aspx being

```
    <asp:Repeater runat="server" ID="rptBugStatus" OnItemDataBound="rptBugStatus_ItemDataBound">

    <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:Label ID="lblBugStatus" runat="server"></asp:Label>
    </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:Repeater>
```

And I have no problems.

- I get the below on the page.

1Under arbete

I think you are going to need to post more code if you have hidden any away from us :)

Tim